# Resolving circular dependency in which each dependent structure accesses it's methods

Tags: c++

How should I resolve the following type of circular dependency?

```
//A.hpp
#include "B.hpp"

struct A {
    B b;
    int foo();
};

//A.cpp
#include "A.hpp"

int A::foo{
    b.fi(*this);
}


//B.hpp
struct A;

struct B {
    int fi(const A &a);
};

//B.cpp
#include "B.hpp"

int B::fi(const A &a){
    if(a.something()) 
        something_else();
}
```

Comment: Use forward declarations

Comment: I can't just forward declare A in B.hpp because in B.cpp, A::something() is called.  Similarly I can't just forward declare B in A.hpp because B::fi(const A&) is called.

Comment: Why can't you do as you do above, but also `#include "A.hpp"` in `B.cpp`?

Comment: Yes, you can.  Forward declare in the `hpp` files, then include `A.hpp` in `B.cpp`.  That's what forward declarations are for.

Comment: can you post real code? include A.hpp in B.cpp should work.

Comment: If you use more descriptive names than `A` and `B`, it may be easier for us to help you improve your design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forward declare `A` in `B.hpp` as you have,, then include `A.hpp` in `B.cpp`. That's what forward declarations are for.

Answer (score 1):

You can define base classes for `A` and `B`, and define `fi` and `something` as virtual functions of these bases in separate headers. Then include these headers from both `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 1):

```
//B.hpp

struct A;

#ifndef B_H    // <-- header guard
#define B_H

struct B {
    int fi(const A &a);
};

#endif

//B.cpp
#include "A.hpp"   // <-- so that fi() can call A::something()
#include "B.hpp"

int B::fi(const A &a){
    if(a.something()) 
        something_else();
}
```